# AVAudioPlayer initialization: error code -50

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-audio

I recently ran into a problem that I couldn't find discussed anywhere on the internet - I was initializing an `AVAudioPlayer` to play an audio file, and getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "Operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)
```

As it turns out, I had made a mistake creating my `NSURL` to send to the audio player `init` method, resulting in the `NSURL` object being null.  Stupid mistake, pretty easy to find when debugging, but I thought I'd list it here just in case someone else does the same thing.

Comment: And for anyone else wondering why their NSURL object is null, if you are creating your NSURL like this and your filename has spaces in it, you'll need to percent encode: `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file with spaces.mp3" ofType:@""];
NSString *path = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];`

Comment: awesome comment pointing out the problem with spaces in file name! huge thanks!

Comment: One possible source for this error is trying to use the AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker option together with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. That doesn't work, you need to use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord - or drop the defaultToSpeaker option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

“ OSStatus error -50” means `paramErr`, an old-style Mac error code indicating a bad parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the comment from Brynjar:
The Apple `NSURL` Class Reference describing `URLWithString` states

> To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use
>   fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: instead.

I have found that using `URLWithString` for file system paths generates the error reported by pix0r and therefore could be another explanation for error code = -50

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `NSURL` is valid, or you will get error code -50 "Operation could not be completed".

Comment: how do I make sure my NSURL is valid? The path is correct and works on the iPad, but when I run it in the simulator it can't find the file... :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my version of the issue and solution because I encountered the error with a print statement. I think it was related to string interpolation and or trying to forcibly print nsattributedstrings. I attempted to do the following.

```
print("THE ARRAY COUNT IS : \(unwrappedResults.count)\n\n\n 
THE FULL ARRAY IS THE FIRST WHOLE RESULT IS: \(unwrappedResults)\n\n\n \ (unwrappedResults[0])\n

THE ATTRIBUTED FULL TEXT IS: \(unwrappedResults[0].attributedFullText)\n\n\n 
THE ATTRIBUTED PRIMARY TEXT IS: \(unwrappedResults[0].attributedPrimaryText)\n\n\n 
THE ATTRIBUTED SECONDARY TEXT IS: \(unwrappedResults[0].attributedSecondaryText)\n\n\n")
```

something about this was incorrect and no print would occur. I would receive the error following errors in my console.

> boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(131) Failed to log metrics
>       &
>       boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(133) Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "Unsupported xpc type"
>   UserInfo={NSDescription=Unsupported xpc type}

I fixed this issue by changing the way I unwrapped/the variables values. Fundamentally I think I was trying to print something using string interpolation that could not be printed and that is what caused this error.